# Copy header to rows where some are blank

Tags: vba, header, copy, rows

I have working code that deletes the blank rows and unnecessary items from the worksheet.

I have a condition where I need to copy the header (in yellow colour) to column A.
Like in the example: Copy Cell B1 to A3, A4,A5 and Copy Cell B6 to A7,A8 and so on.
I did not had any success with If blank. What condition should I apply to accomplish this?
[image]

```vb
Sub Delete_Blank_Rows()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim LngLastRow As Long, lngLastCol As Long, lngIdx As Long, _
        lngColCounter As Long
    Dim blnAllBlank As Boolean
    Dim UserInputSheet As String
    Set wks = Sheets("FNDWRR")
    With wks
        'Now that our sheet is defined, we'll find the last row and last column
        LngLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        lngLastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                             SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        'Since we need to delete rows, we start from the bottom and move up
        For lngIdx = LngLastRow To 1 Step -1
            'Start by setting a flag to immediately stop checking
            'if a cell is NOT blank and initializing the column counter
            blnAllBlank = True
            lngColCounter = 2
            'Check cells from left to right while the flag is True
            'and the we are within the farthest-right column
            While blnAllBlank And lngColCounter <= lngLastCol
                'If the cell is NOT blank, trip the flag and exit the loop
                If .Cells(lngIdx, lngColCounter) <> "" Then
                    blnAllBlank = False
                Else
                    lngColCounter = lngColCounter + 1
                End If
            Wend
            'Delete the row if the blnBlank variable is True
            If blnAllBlank Then
                .Rows(lngIdx).Delete
            End If
        Next lngIdx
    End With
    lRow = 45000
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 7).Value = "Functional Currency" Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next
    Range("b1").EntireColumn.Insert  
End Sub
```

Comment: I can see you are deleting the row if the cell is blank but can't find anywhere where you need to copy the header? Am I missing something? What will trigger the copy? If Cells from column A is blank then copy the header?

Comment: You could use the backround colors. This could give you an idea: "If the background of cell in column B is yellow, copy value into cells below in column A till a cell with background blue" ... (this'll work if your hole sheet follows the pattern of your example (except for "Amt Ord", as below you have the heading of the table, there you'd have to distinguish))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub copyHeaders()
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim holdName As String

    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For r = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(r, 1) = "Hold Name" Then
            holdName = Cells(r, 2).Value
            GoTo NextRow
        End If
        If IsEmpty(Cells(r, 1)) And Not IsNull(holdName) Then Cells(r, 1).Value = holdName
NextRow:
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: This for the quick help. I have checked the code it is returning null value and not pasting the cell b1 to A2,A3,A4 etc.

Comment: Are A2,A3 etc empty cells initially?

Comment: Yes! they are empty. A3,A4,A5 and so on till it detects another "Hold Name" in the corresponding rows.

Comment: Sorry. It was looking for "Hold name" not "Hold Name" (capitalisation). I edited the code. It should work now.

Comment: Many thanks! this code really works flowlessly. However, what should i update if column A is bank and does not contain "Hold Name"

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. Can you please clarify?